# Python BeautifulSoup Extracting PHP Links

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm having a problem in Python with BeautifulSoup.  I need to extract all files on the page that end in ".php", but they also have to be local files.  They can't be from another website.  This is what I have so far:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import mechanize
    import sys

    url = sys.argv[1]

    br = mechanize.Browser()
    code = br.open(url)
    html = code.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

This is where I get stuck on what to do.  I imagine using *soup.findall* to get all the "a href" tags.

Comment: That's a good start... then filter on the `href`s :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.read())

for a in soup.findAll('a'):
  if a['href'].endswith('.php'):
     print a['href']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob,os
path=input("Enter Your Path in "" =")+"//"
print path
for i in glob.glob(os.path.join(str(path),"*.php")):
                   print i
```